# Driving LM317 with pwm signal

Tags: pwm, linear-regulator

I'm trying to drive a LM317T with a PWM signal coming from my Arduino UNO.
Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxK4pL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The PWM frequency is about 500Hz and I'm using a TLC2272 op amp and a LM317T regulator.
If the V_ref of the regulator is 1.25V, shouldn't I get an output voltage 1.25v greater than the adjust voltage?
When I measure V_out - V_adj I get about 2V.

What's wrong with my circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you replace the PWM signal with a fixed voltage?

Comment: Have you tried reading the datasheet how the 317 works? It needs to sink current into the ADJ terminal. Plus it needs a minimal load.

Comment: @CL. no, if i feed a fix voltage it doesn't work either

Comment: @PlasmaHH the datasheet specifies that the I_adj is maxi 100uA, since the op amp can deliver 50mA, shouldn't it be enough to drive the regulator?

Comment: @jagjordi: No, you got this the other way round. The 317 sinks its current into the terminal, it flows *out* of the 317 into somewhere.

Comment: and why can't the op amp "accept" that current? The datasheet spacifies I_out max ±50mA @PlasmaHH

Comment: @jagjordi: The opamp is made for equalizing the *voltage* difference between its terminals, not for adjusting a constant current in or out of any.

Comment: Your circuit is not going to work, the LM317 does not like what you're doing. Have a look here: http://www.picbasic.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=6466  it shows how it can be done. Ignore the first schematic, scroll down to the second one.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention in your question what the *purpose* you're doing this for is, which would make it possible to post a helpful answer. Anyway, there's probably something very conceptually wrong with your approach, so I doubt this schematic makes sense.

Comment: *something very conceptually wrong with your approach* All designs with the LM317 I see **always** have a resistor between *out* and *adj*. Your's doesn't and that makes this circuit "fishy" in my opinion.

Comment: Actually he's using a TLC2272, a bit more modern :-) He could have typed that in the schematic though. OK, I've done it already.

Comment: @FakeMoustache ah, thanks, yeah, I was stupid. But I have exactly that notion: OP wants to do something "special" with his LM317, but forgot to mention. [**XY Problem**](http://xyproblem.info)! (especially if OP's whole problem is to generate a voltage that is 1.5 V higher than the voltage he generates with a low-passed PWM)

Comment: I'm just trying to regulate the output voltage of the LM317 using an arduino to build a very simple power supply. I builded the circuit shown by @FakeMoustache and it works but i don't understand why mine doesn't. I though the LM317 is designed so that the diference between V_out - V_adj  is V_ref (1.25V). I really want to know what's wrong with my original idea. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> shouldn't I get an output voltage 1.25v greater than the adjust voltage?
>   When I measure V_out - V_adj I get about 2V.

Yes, assuming other conditions of the circuit is satisfiedd.

> What's wrong with my circuit?

Read the data sheet thoroughly. The circuit requires some minimum level of current to flow through for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, i missed that part of the datasheet. Now it works as intended